# Typescript definition of nuxt plugins global methods has type any?

Tags: typescript, plugins, vuex, nuxt.js

I have written a Nuxt.js plugin which provides global methods defined by inject property because I need them to be accessible in Vuex store instances either. I have written a type definition file, which I have included in `tsconfig.json`. When I access this global methods in my Nuxt.js application like in a page typing works as expected. When I try to access this methods in an action method inside a store it has type any. How can I augment the types in `vuex/types/index.d.ts` to access my methods with intellisense support and the right typings? This would be great.

Best regards
Moritz

What I have tried out:

After reading this [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) I was able to complete my plugins type definitions. In a similar way I have to do this for Vuex, but I can not figure out which module I have to use.

`plugin-web-connection.ts`:

```
export default ({store, isHMR, app}, inject) => {

  app.store.registerModule('oauth', oAuthStore);
  app.store.registerModule('app-config', appConfigStore);

  inject("getOAuthCredentials", function(stringProp: string) : string {

    console.log("This is an example for getting oAuth: ", stringProp);
    return stringProp;
  });

  inject("doWebRequest", function<T>(method: string, params: any) : 
Promise<T> {
 // content of method does not matter
    }
```

`plugin-web-connection.d.ts`:

```
// 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    $getOAuthCredentials(stringProp: string): string,
    $doWebRequest<T>(method: string, params: any, storeCommit: string): 
Promise<T>
  }
}
```

`menu-store.ts`:

```
export const state = (): sabioTree => ({

});

export const mutations = {
    setMenu(state: sabioTree, newState: sabioTree) {}
}

export const actions = {

    retrieveMenu(context: any, data: any) {

        var method: string = data.method;
        var parametersObj: any = data.parameters;
        var storeCommit: string = data.storeCommit;

        debugger;

        // this is underlined red by VS-Code because of the generic!! this.$doWebRequest has type any
        this.$doWebRequest<sabioTree>(method, parametersObj, storeCommit).
        then(function(s) {})
    }
 }
```